# Cooking Sweet Potatos in the Microwave

Tags: cooking-time, microwave, sweet-potatoes

What are the recommended times for cooking sweet potatoes in the microwave?

Microwave wattage associated with those times would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a typical 1200 W to 1400 W microwave

For gold (skin and interior) sweet potato around 4 to 5 minutes per 300 g (large first size)

For purple (skin, and cream interior) sweet potato around 5 to 6 minutes per 300 g

Allow at least a minute sitting time before cutting or serving to allow for an even cook

Answer (score 2):

i cook sweet potatoes in microwave. I cut them up and put them into tupperware style container. The more sweet potato i put in; the longer i cook it. For a lot of it; it might be as much as 14 - 17 minutes. For a little; 7 - 10 minutes.

Comment: Hi lauran, and welcome to the site! As you can see, I edited your answer and left a part out. If this happens, don't worry, this is the way this site works. As for in the future, please do not make health claims (true or not), because we do not handle these on this site. Here it is just about food and cooking itself, not what is healthy or good for you. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Technique is basically the same as a normal potato: poke it full of holes with a fork, and microwave on high for 5-10 minutes, depending on size of the potato.  The fork holes let steam escape.  Cook times are assuming a roughly 1000W microwave.  I suggest checking the potato's progress by sticking it with a fork every couple minutes, to make sure you don't overdo it.

If you want a crispier skin, you can finish with a few minutes in the toaster oven at 450F/230C.

Comment: Sweet potatoes cook in 50% to 70% of the time a similar potato would cook in. 7-12 minutes will turn them to stringy mush

Comment: @TFS: Maybe they cook a *little* faster.  I can [cite](http://kitchen-parade-veggieventure.blogspot.com/2007/08/delicious-microwave-sweet-potato.html) a source indicating 7 minutes is not outrageous;  I'm used to pretty large and starchy sweet potatoes, however.  And mushy is not necessarily a bad thing.  I'll adjust my suggested time range down a little bit though, since they do cook somewhat faster.